# Word wrapping in graph

Tags: iphone, ios, graph, nsstring, word-wrap

I have a bar graph in which I need to write Place name for every bar, but sometimes the name is very long. How can I put whole name and wrap is properly according to width of bar ?

I am using the following code

```
 NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.myTopNameStr];


[percentage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(_histogramStartX + 5,_xaxisStart.y - _ySpacingScale*item.yValue - 25) forWidth:80 withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
```

but result is not as expected, I can't see the full name.

[image]

Comment: have you used `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` in `lineBreakMode`?

Comment: I've tried `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` but I am not getting the full name.

Comment: I think you would be better off by using `– drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:`; calculate the rect with `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString * percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.myTopNameStr];
CGSize percentageSize = [percentage sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10] forWidth:80 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

[percentage drawInRect:CGRectMake(_histogramStartX + 5,_xaxisStart.y - _ySpacingScale*item.yValue - 25, percentageSize.width, percentageSize.height) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
```

Comment: I am getting `percentageSize.height` = 13 that is not enough for full name, so I put `150` instead of `percentageSize.height`. everything else is good.